# How to convert int to wstring?

Tags: c++

I want to convert an integer value (int) to std::wstring.
What is the best way to do this?
I cannot use to_wstring for some reasons.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's patently clear what is being asked here, is there any way to appeal these whimsical question closures?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [`std::wostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
int i = 10;
std::wostringstream ws;
ws << i;
const std::wstring s(ws.str());
```

Or, [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html):

```
#include <boost\lexical_cast.hpp>
const std::wstring s(boost::lexical_cast<std::wstring>(10));
```

---

To convert back, use a [`wistringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
std::wistringstream win(L"10");
int x;
if (win >> x && win.eof())
{
    // The eof ensures all stream was processed and
    // prevents acccepting "10abc" as valid ints.
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! but how about to convert a wstring to int ?

Comment: @Ryan_Liu same thing backward, create a `wistringstream` with the `wstring` and read an `int` out of it.

Answer (score -3):

you can use itoa to convert int to char and initialize your std::wstring with this char

Comment: I assume you're talking about `char*` not `char`.

Comment: `itoa` is neither part of C++ nor of C.